# is dask really faster than pandas?

Tags: pandas, dask

I am looking at processing a large dataframe (10m rows), and am doing some benchmarking with dask. I am new to dask, so maybe I did not set it up correctly.

my df has 7m rows, and 14 columns.

```
import dask
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
import sys
timer = []
for cnt in range(10):
    ddf = from_pandas(df, npartitions=cnt+1)
    for j in range(3):
        t0 = pd.Timestamp.now()
        d = ddf[(ddf['FIRSTNAME'] == 'first') & (ddf['LASTNAME'] == 'last') & (ddf['dob']== 'yyyy-mm-dd')].compute()
        t1=(pd.Timestamp.now() - t0).total_seconds()

        t0 = pd.Timestamp.now()
        d = df[(df['FIRSTNAME'] == 'first') & (df['LASTNAME'] == 'last') & (df['dob']== 'yyyy-mm-dd')]
        t2=(pd.Timestamp.now() - t0).total_seconds()
        timer.append([cnt+1, j, t1,t2])
df = pd.DataFrame(timer, columns = ['partition','B','ddf','df'])
df.groupby('partition').mean()
```

the results show me:

```
             B       ddf        df
partition
1          1.0  3.548936  3.612199
2          1.0  3.556940  3.088862
3          1.0  3.097758  3.052725
4          1.0  4.054630  3.715735
5          1.0  3.391483  3.115667
6          1.0  3.241238  3.152429
7          1.0  3.676911  3.048394
8          1.0  3.395394  3.395397
9          1.0  3.183287  3.164195
10         1.0  3.306066  3.068059
```

1 or 8 partitions is faster than pandas. I am using an 8 core processor. Does dask utilize all the cores? Is there a way to make it a little faster?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this part of the dask documentation: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-best-practices.html#use-pandas

Dask excels at out-of-core computing (data that doesn't fit into memory) and distributed computing (using the resources of up to thousands of machines).

It might make an in-memory pandas workflow like this faster if they release the GIL. In your case, this will be the case for pure-vectorised operations like the ANDs, and may be the case for string equal operations with the arrow string backend only. However, dask also adds overhead for organising the threads (or processes), in particular in concatenating the outputs of the partitions into a single dataframe.

> is dask really faster?

It depends! No software is magic.